# Apache server don't load extensions (Windows 10, PHP 8.0.12, Apache 2.4.46, (WAMP3.2.3))

Tags: php, apache, wamp, php-8

Apache don't load some modules. I need to use phpMyAdmin but it says mysqli is missing. I'm stuck with this since days... Thanks  for your help ! Tell me what informations you need... I've set my path in my php.ini used by Apache this way :

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
;extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
extension_dir = C:/wamp64/bin/php/php8.0.12/ext
upload_tmp_dir = C:/wamp64/tmp
error_log = C:/wamp64/tmp
```

my wampserver.conf is set this way :

```
<?php

$phpConf['phpIniDir'] = '.';
$phpConf['phpExeDir'] = '.';
$phpConf['phpConfFile'] = 'php.ini';

$phpConf['apache']['2.2']['LoadModuleName'] = 'php5_module';
$phpConf['apache']['2.2']['LoadModuleFile'] = 'php5apache2_2.dll';
$phpConf['apache']['2.2']['AddModule'] =  '';

$phpConf['apache']['2.4']['LoadModuleName'] = 'php_module';
$phpConf['apache']['2.4']['LoadModuleFile'] = 'php8apache2_4.dll';
$phpConf['apache']['2.4']['AddModule'] =  '';

?>
```

Some modules are loaded but others are not, here there's a picture to illustrate my problem :

[image: description]

Comment: You should update to the latest version of WAMPServer which is 3.2.5 this may fix that issue

Answer (score 0):

Update WAMPManager to be able to use the latest versions of PHP Apache etc

You can find the latest updates to WAMPmanager and the latest ADDONs on the [WAMPServer Backup Repo](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en)

Its easier to navigate than SourceForge

> Updates only "Wampmanager", does not add any Apache PHP, MySQL or MariaDB versions. It is a cumulative update. It is not necessary to apply the old updates 3.0.1 to 3.2.4 before applying 3.2.5. There will be no changes to your Apache, PHP, MySQL, MariaDB settings and versions used; your local sites and databases will not be affected. **This update is necessary to install the latest Apache, PHP, MySQL or MariaDB addons.**

Comment: thank you, it works better, I can go on phpmyadmin now but there is a lot of errors... Should I move to the last MySQL version, does it will affect phpMyAdmin ? Plus, still none of my extensions are ticked in green like normaly when I use php7.4.9 for example... I don't think that this is normal...